# (No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping) in ubuntu

Tags: monitoring, nagios3

I installed nagios following this tutorial
http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/02/08/install-and-configure-nagios-core-4-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

On starting nagios and apache2, and browsing to nagios admin portal, I saw errors like below

```
(No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping)

(No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http)

(No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you install nagios 4 following this tutorial [http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/02/08/install-and-configure-nagios-core-4-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/"](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/02/08/install-and-configure-nagios-core-4-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/%22), then your installation directory is `/usr/local/nagios`. On starting nagios and browsing to nagios admin portal, you could see the following errors

```
(No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping
(No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_users
(No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http
```

This is how I fixed the above errors, Install plugins

```
sudo apt-get install nagios-plugins
```

This will install all plugins to /usr/lib/nagios/plugins directory.

Just copy all files starting with `check_*` to `/usr/local/nagios/libexec`.

```
cp /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_* /usr/local/nagios/libexec
```

or

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_* /usr/local/nagios/libexec/
```

and wait for nagios to reload/refresh browser window.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to install it from sources:

```
cd ~
curl -L -O http://nagios-plugins.org/download/nagios-plugins-2.2.1.tar.gz
tar zxf nagios-plugins-*.tar.gz
cd nagios-plugins-*
./configure --with-nagios-user=nagios --with-nagios-group=nagios --with-openssl
make
sudo make install
```

Hope, it'll be helpful.

Comment: How will that fix OPs problem ?

Comment: What do you mean saying "OPs problem"?
As I can see from the first post, nagios were installed, but without it's plugins. That worked for me.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I think your answer was the right direction, but you didn't identify the problem.  Since the OP's question wasn't "how do I install plugins" you needed to say that was the issue, _then_ go about explaining how to install them.

Answer (score 1):

The OP hasn't installed the necessary plugins.

[Instructions to install plugins](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/quickstart.html) can be found from the official docs - just select the platform you are using and scroll down to the 'Installing The Nagios Plugins' section.